# 2 buttons in xaml wp8 phone:PivotItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Button "playsound" displays fine by itself, but whenever I add "button2" I get following error:

> Property content is set more than once.

and

> Invalid Markup.

in my design view. How do I get more than one button on my pivot?

```
<phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Audio" Margin="41,30,8,-58">
    <Button x:Name="button2" Margin="61,301,0,0" Content="hello" Height="22" Width="33"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="playsound" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,451,0,0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="109" Width="256">
        <Grid Height="138" Width="293" RenderTransformOrigin="0.349,0.43">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width ="110"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width ="110"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,68">
                <Run Text="יום ראשון&#10;"/>
                <Run Text="Sunday"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,68">
                <Run Text="פרק כד&#10;"/>
                <Run Text="Psalm 24"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button>                    
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Comment: nest the two buttons in StackPanel, bro (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the two buttons inside a container element such as a `Grid` or a `StackPanel`:

```
<Grid>
    //Buttons here
</Grid>
```

or

```
<StackPanel>
    //Buttons here
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. PivotItem allow only one child element. that's why you getting error. use a Container control like stackpanel or grid as a child of PivotItem .

```
<phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Audio" Margin="41,30,8,-58">
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button2"  Content="hello" Height="22" Width="33"/>
    <Button x:Name="playsound" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="109" Width="256">
                        <Grid Height="138" Width="293" RenderTransformOrigin="0.349,0.43">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width ="110"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width ="110"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,68">
                                <Run Text="יום ראשון&#10;"/>
                                <Run Text="Sunday"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,68">
                            <Run Text="פרק כד&#10;"/>
                            <Run Text="Psalm 24"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>   
  </StackPanel>                 
 </phone:PivotItem>
```